# ASP.NET core iframe authentication cookie

Tags: html, asp.net-core, iframe, razor-pages, x-frame-options

I'm having some trouble with my iframe. Whenever I try to login it seems that my authentication cookie isn't working since I just get redirected back to my login screen. How can I fix this?

The cookie works fine when I'm just running the website normally, but as soon as I display it in iframe it all goes to hell.

Here is my Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
          
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(o =>
            {
                o.Conventions.ConfigureFilter(new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IgnoreAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
                
            });

            // Here we set some settings for the authentication cookie, with the class CookieAuthenticationOptions which is a part of the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies namespace.
            services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie(options =>
            {
                // Here we set the name of the authentication cookie.
                options.Cookie.Name = "AuthCookie";
                // Here we set the cookie to Http Only, because no scripts should have access to change the cookie.
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                // Here we set the cookie to be only send over an HTTPS connection.
                options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.None;
                // Here we set the SameSite to lax, because not all browser's set cookies without a SameSite value to lax.
                options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;
                // Here we set the path to the Access denied site to our AccessDenied site. The site is shown if a user don't have access to the site he/she/it is trying to visit.
                options.AccessDeniedPath = "/";
                // Here we set the login page. The user is redirected to this site if he/she/it is not logged in and the site require the user to be logged in.
                options.LoginPath = "/";
                // Here we set the log out site.
                options.LogoutPath = "/Logout";
            });

        }

        




        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }


            /* app.Use(async (context, next) =>
             {
                 //
                 //context.Response.Headers.Remove("X-Frame-Options");
                 context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Frame-Options", "DENY");
             });*/

            app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                context.Response.Headers.Remove("X-Frame-Options");
                context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Frame-Options", "ALLOWALL");
                //context.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Security-Policy", "frame-ancestors https://kasp151f.000webhostapp.com/");
                await next();
            });

            // app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            // Here I enable authentication capeabilities for the website.
            app.UseAuthentication();
            // Here I enable authorization capeabilities for the website.
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();
            
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }

    }
```

And here is my Iframe:

```
<iframe width="1280" height="720" frameBorder="0"  scrolling="no"  onload="HandleLocationChange(this, this.contentWindow.location.href)" src="http://kasperssejeside.tk/"></iframe>
```

Comment: Do you mean render your website in another application using the iframe tag? Try to use F12 developer tools to check the cookie, whether it is exist or not, and make sure it's not expired, Then, try to clear the cookie and re-check whether it works or not?

Comment: i checket and the cookie exists but its like the parameters arent getting set in it

Answer (score 2):

As Halvor suggested, it is indeed a SameSite cookie issue. This article describes a fix: [Upcoming SameSite Cookie Changes in ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/upcoming-samesite-cookie-changes-in-asp-net-and-asp-net-core/)

Summary: you need the to set the `SameSite` option to `none` to allow the cookie to be used despite the `iframe`. The catch: it will break for browsers for which this option was not available. For these, you need to leave the option out.

Implementation for asp.net core (taken from the above-mentioned article with small changes):
All changes are in `Startup.cs`.
Add this to the body of `ConfigureServices(...)`:

```
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
{
    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Unspecified;
    options.OnAppendCookie = cookieContext =>
        cookieContext.CookieOptions.SameSite = DisallowsSameSiteNone(cookieContext.Context) ? SameSiteMode.Unspecified : SameSiteMode.None;  
    options.OnDeleteCookie = cookieContext =>
        cookieContext.CookieOptions.SameSite = DisallowsSameSiteNone(cookieContext.Context) ? SameSiteMode.Unspecified : SameSiteMode.None;
    options.Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.Always; // required for chromium-based browsers

});
```

Add this to the body of `Configure(...)` before `app.UseAuthentication()`

```
app.UseCookiePolicy();
```

And add this method

```
private static bool DisallowsSameSiteNone(HttpContext httpContext)
{
    var userAgent = httpContext.Request.Headers["User-Agent"].ToString();

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userAgent))
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Cover all iOS based browsers here. This includes:
    // - Safari on iOS 12 for iPhone, iPod Touch, iPad
    // - WkWebview on iOS 12 for iPhone, iPod Touch, iPad
    // - Chrome on iOS 12 for iPhone, iPod Touch, iPad
    // All of which are broken by SameSite=None, because they use the iOS networking stack
    if (userAgent.Contains("CPU iPhone OS 12") || userAgent.Contains("iPad; CPU OS 12"))
    {
        return true;
    }

    // Cover Mac OS X based browsers that use the Mac OS networking stack. This includes:
    // - Safari on Mac OS X.
    // This does not include:
    // - Chrome on Mac OS X
    // Because they do not use the Mac OS networking stack.
    if (userAgent.Contains("Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14") &&
        userAgent.Contains("Version/") && userAgent.Contains("Safari"))
    {
        return true;
    }

    // Cover Chrome 50-69, because some versions are broken by SameSite=None, 
    // and none in this range require it.
    // Note: this covers some pre-Chromium Edge versions, 
    // but pre-Chromium Edge does not require SameSite=None.
    if (userAgent.Contains("Chrome/5") || userAgent.Contains("Chrome/6"))
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds more like a SameSite cookie issue. To test this try disabling SameSite settings in Chrome, chrome://flags/#same-site-by-default-cookies, or check if it works in IE.

If this fixes your problem you will need to modify the SameSite flag on one or more cookies.